# ¿Cuál sería la expresión regular de un número de dos o cuatro digitos?

Tags: regex

Necesito una expresión regular para validar un año, el cual puede estar en formato de dos o cuatro dígitos.

Por lo tanto:

```sh
00     PASA
01     PASA
11     PASA
99     PASA
2020   PASA
3000   PASA
3021   PASA

1      NO PASA
123    NO PASA
43221  NO PASA
215467 NO PASA
```

Comment: Hay que ser precisos con el idioma, sobre todo al especificar requerimientos... "entre dos y cuatro dígitos" significa dos, **tres** o cuatro dígitos, no dos o cuatro.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar

```
^(\d{2}|\d{4})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/llFw03/1)

Puedo intentar explicarlo, pero Regex101 lo hace mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

La siguiente expresión cumple con tus requerimientos:

`^(\d{2}|\d{4})$`

En general, si quieres que una regex se cumpla `n` o `m` veces en dónde `n>m`, podrías usar la siguiente:

`^X{m}(X{k})?$`

en donde `X` es la regex (en este caso solamente números: `\d`) y `k=n-m` (en este caso `n=4`, `m=2`, `k=2`)

Entonces tu regex quedaría de la siguiente manera:

`^\d{2}(\d{2})?$`

Answer (score 2):

Solo por el placer de hacerlo complicado (*)

```
^(\d{2}){1,2}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4loYlb/1)

(*) Naturalmente, para el código de verdad, el KISS y PLA significan que has de coger la opción más sencilla, así que las otras respuestas previas son mejores (aunque menos divertidas).